# Progress bar in CSS with constant speed of movement regardless of the length

Tags: html, css

I made a progress bar with the following CSS:

```css
.progress-bar-short,
.progress-bar-long {
  animation-duration: 2.2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: 200ms;
  will-change: left, right;
}

.progress-bar-short {
  animation-name: indeterminate-short-ltr;
}

.progress-bar-long {
  animation-name: indeterminate-ltr;
}

@keyframes indeterminate-ltr {
  0% {
    left: -90%;
    right: 100%;
  }
  60% {
    left: -90%;
    right: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    right: -35%;
  }
}

@keyframes indeterminate-short-ltr {
  0% {
    left: -200%;
    right: 100%;
  }
  60% {
    left: 107%;
    right: -8%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 107%;
    right: -8%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="progress-bar-long" style="left: 0%; right: 100%; top: 0; bottom: 0; position: absolute; background-color: red;"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar-short" style="left: 0%; right: 100%; top: 0; bottom: 0; position: absolute; background-color: red;"></div>
</div>
```

I think it is a pretty standard progress bar. What I find problematic though is that depending on the length (width, size) of the progress bar the speed of the movement changes. Longer it is, speed is faster as animation has to traverse larger distance to finish the animation on time (in 2.2s). Because I would like to use the same progress bar for site-level progress bar on top and smaller progress bar inside components, this bothers me.

How could I make a progress bar which moves at a constant speed regardless of the length of the progress bar?

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/mitar/pen/yLEdYxy).

Comment: Can i use javascript for that?

Answer (score 12):

Try this pure CSS solution with **calc()** function and variables, we use them is to change duration and transform. So we need an absolute width value, because with pure CSS we can't find the relative width value like in JavaScript. In the `.progress` class has the`--speed`, `--width` and `--duration` variables, which an important because we use them for calculations. Increasing `--speed` will make animation play faster and decreasing `--speed` will slow it down.

> Why I'm using the `transform` property instead of the `left`. [web.dev](https://web.dev/animations-guide/)

#### Update:

For responsive design, you can use media query breakpoints  to change the `--length` variable and we have two ways: use a variable inside a class (or add extra class) or change the variable with `!important`.

```css
.progress-bar {
  --height: 3rem;
  width: calc(var(--length) * 1px);
  height: var(--height);
  outline: 1px solid rgb(125, 164, 255);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* example with responsive class */
.flexible-class {
  --length: 450;
  outline: 1px solid rgb(238, 125, 255);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  .flexible-class {
    --length: 350;
  }
  .progress-bar {
    /* --length: 350 !important; */ /* if you want change inline variable*/
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .flexible-class {
    --length: 250;
  }
  .progress-bar {
    /* --length: 250 !important; */ /* if you want change inline variable*/
  }
}

.progress {
  --speed: 50;
  --width: 80;  /* 5rem / 5 * 16 = 80 */
  --duration: calc((var(--width) + var(--length)) / var(--speed) * 1s);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(-1px * var(--width));
  background-color: rgb(68, 0, 255);
  height: inherit;
  width: calc(1px * var(--width));
  animation-duration: var(--duration);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: 200ms;
  animation-name: animation;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes animation {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc((var(--length) + var(--width)) * 1px));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar" style="--length: 450">
  <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
<div class="progress-bar" style="--length: 350">
  <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
<div class="progress-bar" style="--length: 250">
  <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
<div class="progress-bar flexible-class">
  <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a nice answer, I think you just need to add the `--width` in the calcul of the duration or you will get a tiny speed difference, I made an answer which is really close to yours if you wanna see the difference

Comment: @Cédric Yes, you are right. The `--width` should be calculated in the `--duration` just as **rem** is changed to **px** for accuracy. I didn't notice this slight shift, because `animation-timing-function;` has by default  `ease;`

Comment: I think this is a nice answer, but it side-steps the question how you get to make a responsive progress bar by having it be a fixed (but configurable) length. Maybe I was unclear about that, but I would like that if length of the progress bar changes because of layout changes (window resizing, simply layout sizing of some other element), progress bar adapts automatically. Imagine a progress bar which is inside a button element: length of the progress bar depends on the contents of the button.

Comment: In this case, you can use a media query and add breakpoints, where you change the variable. And instead inline style, use class with variable or use `!important` to override inline style (I don't like use `!important` property myself, if I don't need it). I updated the snippet.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is probably truly as close as possible to do. It is not yet exactly what I had in mind, but it will have to do. From what I there is no way in CSS to fill a variable based on some other DOM element width or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple progress bar using javascript which has a constant speed :D

**How it works?**

What it does is each millisecond it traverses one or two or three pixels ... (depending on the value given to the first variable called "Pixles_traversed_in_ms ") and inside that interval, we check if the progress bar has reached the end of it's container, if so we set the pixels to 0 s which means it will go back to the very left of the container. and it keeps doing that again and again.

```js
let Pixles_traversed_in_ms = 2; // Change this to lower or increase the speed

// Variables
let container = document.querySelector('.container')
let progress_bar = document.querySelector('.container .progress_bar');

let pixels = 1;
setInterval(()=>{
  pixels += Pixles_traversed_in_ms
  progress_bar.style.left = pixels + 'px';
  if (pixels >= container.clientWidth ) {
    pixels = - progress_bar.clientWidth;
  }
}, 1)
```

```css
.container {
  width:100%;
  background:#f48225;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.container .progress_bar {
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:100%;
  background:black;
  /* You can get rid of these style below*/
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:12px;
  color:#f48225;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress_bar">
      Progress Bar :D
  </div>
</div>
```

[Live Preview](https://codepen.io/Mr-montasir/pen/jOpOZEE)

Answer (score 2):

I tryed to find a solution and basically found the same thing as [Anton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15545116/anton)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74856115/17684809), I just added the progress length to the calcul of the duration.

```css
:root {
  --progress-width: 50;
  --speed: 100;
}

.w-25 {
  --bar-width: calc(250 - var(--progress-width));
}

.w-50 {
  --bar-width: calc(500 - var(--progress-width));
}

.w-75 {
  --bar-width: calc(750 - var(--progress-width));
}

.w-100 {
  --bar-width: calc(1000 - var(--progress-width));
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(var(--bar-width) * 1px);
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(var(--progress-width) * 1px);
  height: 100%;
  left: calc(-1px * var(--progress-width));
  animation: animation calc((var(--bar-width) + var(--progress-width)) / var(--speed) * 1000ms) linear infinite;
  background-color: red;
}

@keyframes animation {
  to {
    transform: translateX(calc((var(--bar-width) + var(--progress-width)) * 1px));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bar w-25">
  <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
<div class="bar w-50">
  <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
<div class="bar w-75">
  <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
<div class="bar w-100">
  <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
```

Originaly I tryed to make it in pure css but with percentages, I realized I don't think you can because you need to get the value in the duration calcul.

For example, if your screen width is 1024px width and your bar is 25% (and the progress width is 50px), the calcul will be :

(25% of 1024 + 50px)/100 * 1s = (256 + 50)/100 * 1s = 3.06s
So the speed will be 306px/3.06s = 100px/s

If we chose 50%, the calcul will be :

(50% of 1024 + 50px)/100 * 1s = (512 + 50)/100 * 1s = 5.62s
So the speed will be 562px/5.62s = 100px/s

The speed are the same, using percentage.

The problem is that you can't make this calcul in css because you don't know that the screen width is 1024px (so you get 50% of ?)

Here is a cheat that will only work on screen = 1024px because I specified `--window-width: 1024` to do the math. I used `right` for the animation for the same reason, I don't know the length of the parent (you still could use translateX if you wrap the progress in a container having a `width:100%` and apply the animation to it).

```css
:root {
  --progress-width: 50;
  --speed: 100;
  --window-width: 1024;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.w-25 {
  --bar-width: 25;
}

.w-50 {
  --bar-width: 50;
}

.w-75 {
  --bar-width: 75;
}

.w-100 {
  --bar-width: 100;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(var(--bar-width) * 1%);
  height: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
  margin: 10px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(var(--progress-width) * 1px);
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  right: calc(100% + 1px * var(--progress-width));
  animation: animation calc((var(--bar-width) * var(--window-width) / 100 + 2 * var(--progress-width)) / var(--speed) * 1000ms) linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animation {
  to {
    right: calc(-1px * var(--progress-width));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bar w-25">
  <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
<div class="bar w-50">
  <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
<div class="bar w-75">
  <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
<div class="bar w-100">
  <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a multitude of solutions to your code. The problem with your code is that since the units are in percentages the speed will change based on much of the progress bar is filled. I recommend setting your units to px or making a calculator to find how much to fill up based on how much of the bar is already filled.(Like some others already made)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).